# Find all unique values for field in Elasticsearch through python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I've been scouring the web for some good python documentation for Elasticsearch. I've got a query term that I know returns the information I need, but I'm struggling to convert the raw string into something Python can interpret.

This will return a list of all unique 'VALUE's in the dataset.

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "hierarchy1.hierarchy2.VALUE"}
```

Which I have taken from a dashboarding tool which accesses this data.
But I don't seem to be able to convert this into correct python.

I've tried this:

```
body_test = {"find": "terms", "field": "hierarchy1.hierarchy2.VALUE"}
es = Elasticsearch(SETUP CONNECTION)
es.search(
    index="INDEX_NAME",
    body = body_test
)
```

but it doesn't like the `find` value. I can't find anything in the documentation about `find`.

> RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for
> a VALUE_STRING in [find].')

The only way I've got it to slightly work is with

```
es_search = (
        Search(
            using=es,
            index=db_index
        ).source(['hierarchy1.hierarchy2.VALUE'])
    )
```

But I think this is pulling the entire dataset and then filtering (which I obviously don't want to be doing each time I run this code). This needs to be done through python and so I cannot simply POST the query I know works.

I am completely new to ES and so this is all a little confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the `find` in this case was specific to Grafana (the dashboarding tool I took the query from.
[In the end I used this site and used the code from there. It's a LOT more complicated than I thought it was going to be. But it works very quickly and doesn't put a strain on the database (which my alternative method was doing).](https://techoverflow.net/2019/03/17/how-to-query-distinct-field-values-in-elasticsearch/)

In case the link dies in future years, here's the code I used:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

def iterate_distinct_field(es, fieldname, pagesize=250, **kwargs):
    """
    Helper to get all distinct values from ElasticSearch
    (ordered by number of occurrences)
    """
    compositeQuery = {
        "size": pagesize,
        "sources": [{
                fieldname: {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": fieldname
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    # Iterate over pages
    while True:
        result = es.search(**kwargs, body={
            "aggs": {
                "values": {
                    "composite": compositeQuery
                }
            }
        })
        # Yield each bucket
        for aggregation in result["aggregations"]["values"]["buckets"]:
            yield aggregation
        # Set "after" field
        if "after_key" in result["aggregations"]["values"]:
            compositeQuery["after"] = \
                result["aggregations"]["values"]["after_key"]
        else: # Finished!
            break

# Usage example
for result in iterate_distinct_field(es, fieldname="pattern.keyword", index="strings"):
    print(result) # e.g. {'key': {'pattern': 'mypattern'}, 'doc_count': 315}
```